# Using reflections in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

My controller is returning a partial view like this

```
return View("MyPartialView", MyModel);
```

but it could as well pass in another model

```
return View("MyPartialView", AnotherModel);
```

I'd now like to retrieve `typeof()` from the partial view. To do so, I've declared (in the view)

```
@model object
```

and

```
Type modelType = typeof(model);
```

However

> The type or namespace 'model' could not be found

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to use reflections in a partial view? If yes, how?

Be it a `Customer` or a `Product`, the editor is the same. Hence, I want to iterate over the properties and display a text field for each one of them: do I really need a separate view for every model? If I could use a single view that would be awesome!

Comment: Wondering why you need Reflection? Views has to be simple as far as it can be.

Comment: Having 30 views with 10 or more properties each VS having 1 view with 1 line of code printing out the properties of the model I give it. The second one is what I have in mind. I will be raped if I'll need more complexity in the view but I already know this will not need more than a single text field for each property.

Comment: `model` should be with a capital M (`Model`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Type modelType = typeof(model);
```

Your `model` is a variable (property) here, not a Type. Use:

```
 Type modelType = model.GetType();
```

But seriously, one guideline in MVC is that Views should be *simple*. I am very skeptical about this kind of design.

Comment: GetType and capital M solved the issue. Thanks! The view will be very simple and I won't use the same design for more complicated stuff: thanks for your advice!